# How do I run test-app from within a gant script?

Tags: grails, gant

I would like to execute some additional script steps after each test run.
So basically, I would like to create a new script in grails which

- first calls the standard `test-app functional:webtest -baseUrl=http://example.com`
- afterwards runs some kind of clean-up script

Now I wonder about how to call the `test-app`script from within my script...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The common way to do that is shown in this example:

```
scriptEnv = "test"

includeTargets << grailsScript("_GrailsInit")
includeTargets << grailsScript("_GrailsClean")
includeTargets << grailsScript("_GrailsTest")


target(main: "Testing app (unit coverage)") {
    echo "Testing app (unit coverage)"

    argsMap << ["unit":'']
    argsMap << ["coverage":'']
    phasesToRun = ['unit']

    allTests()
}

setDefaultTarget(main)
```

The line `grailsScript("_GrailsInit")` does the trick and inlcudes the targets of the grails scripts into the own.

You can have a look at this http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/commandLine.html#creatingGantScripts

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to use the execute.shell command like so:

```
includeTool << gant.tools.Execute

target(main: "Run script") {
    execute.shell("grails test-app functional:webtest -baseUrl=http://example.com")
    //Proceed with cleanup code here...
}
```

See http://gant.codehaus.org/Execute+Tool for more information.

Comment: Is this really the right way? There should be a better way to start one script from within another. Your solution will start grails twice...

Comment: There is a better way to run another gant script, but to run a Grails task I have not found a better way I'm afraid.  I could be wrong, but this is the only solution I've found.  A 'better' way would probably be to write an inline plugin, the amount of effort required needs to be balanced against your ultimate goal. In my case, I wanted a quick an easy way to execute another grails plugin from the command line.  This was the solution I found.

Comment: I wonder if this will start another Grails environment with another JVM and everything...

Comment: My original answer is based on outdated code. I believe that matcauthon's answer is the correct one today.